# Reading Postgress (encoded in SQL_ASCII) from Data Factory

Tags: postgresql, azure, character-encoding, azure-data-factory

I am trying to read a on-premise postgres Database that is encoded in SQL_ASCII from the Azure Data Factory Copy Data Activity in order to copy the database's data into a Azure Data Lake.

I am running into encoding issues with special characters such as "è" an "é" and I am quite clueless as to how I should go about fixing this.

When seting up my source Dataset provinding a given table, it's preview shows the characters as "?". Does anyone have an idea of how I could fix this ?

Note that I cannot change the database's encoding because it is not under my control.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix/workaround my issue by using the Postgres ANSI ODBC driver (64 bits) and specifying the DSN as an additional property on the Postgres Linked Service inside Azure Data Factory